# Get current active connection to the database

Tags: mysql, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to get the current number of active connection the to database from the rails server. I have another java server which also connects to the same database

Basically I can get the current connections to database from mysql using

```sql
SHOW STATUS like '%onnect%'
```

but that would be combination of both rails and java connections.

How can I get the connections from rails server only, is there any method in `ActiveRecord::Base` which can give this info directly (using rails 3.2.17/ ruby 2.1)

Comment: Are they using the same MySQL user?

Comment: Yes, they are using the same user

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection_handler.connection_pool_list.map { |pool| pool.connections.length }.inject(:+)
```

For rails-3 you should try to patch `class ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionPool`:

```
class ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionPool
  attr_reader :connections
end
```

and then try:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection_handler.connection_pools.values.compact.map { |pool| pool.connections.length }.inject(:+)
```

Comment: I am getting undefined method connection_pool_list

Comment: What type id you `connection_handler`?

Comment: connection_pool_list is not available in rails 3.2.17